# QGIS Temporal Controller dynamic text

Tags: qgis, time, dynamic

I have a temporal dataset and it animates and I have a dynamic title displaying the time period, but I am unable to get a dynamic label to report the length of the linear features at that time period.

```
aggregate( 'Lines',
 aggregate:= 'sum',
 expression:=  $length ,
 filter:=  'DT_CREATED' >= @map_start_time )
```

No matter the filter I get the same value, it stays the same throughout the animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the field in the filter must be in double quotes:

```
aggregate( 'Lines',
aggregate:= 'sum',
expression:=  $length ,
filter:=  "DT_CREATED" >= @map_start_time )
```

Comment: That's fabulous and answered my question but now I am unable to figure out how to only sum the lengths of the features visible in the map between @map_start_time and @map_end_time?
``` filter:= (intersects(  $geometry, @map_extent )) AND
 (  ("DT_CREATED">@map_start_time AND("UNTIL">@map_start_time OR "UNTIL" < @map_end_time) OR 
 ("DT_CREATED"<@map_start_time AND ("UNTIL" > @map_start_time OR "UNTIL"> @map_end_time) ))))```
seems to complex, must be easier!

Comment: It's better to post a new question for that, then you will reach more people who would or could help with that!